# URL rewriting : Adding a hash after hostname

Tags: .htaccess, hash, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite my website URL's like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/title-of-article
redirection to: http://www.mywebsite.com/#title-of-article ("#" after hostname)

I can not find the right formula for my htaccess file.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /#$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you, Jon Lin! It works. How can I do the same with: http://www.mywebsite.com/category/title-of-article to http://www.mywebsite.com/category/#title-of-article ?